# Drag image from Gimp / Kolourpaint to another application

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, kde, gimp, jira

Some applications, such as the Jira issue tracker, allow one to upload a file by simply dragging it into the browser window:

[image: Jira file upload]

In KDE 4.14 on CentOS 7.3 I can drag files from the file manager Dolphin to Jira, but I cannot drag the open image in Gimp or Kolourpaint directly into Jira as I've seen my Max OSX using counterparts do with whatever simple image editor comes with that OS. Is there any way to get this functionality in Gimp, Kolourpaint, or another Linux app?

I would rather not save the images then drag them over as these are screenshots of application bugs and it would double the amount of time spent on an issue to save the image, then open another app, then drag it, then remove the saved image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy-paste from Gimp:

1. In Gimp: *Select>All* and *Edit>Copy*
2. Anywhere in the JIRA page: Ctrl-V. This is automatically converted into a screenshot attachment.

(tested with Kubuntu 14.04, Gimp 2.8.18 and Firefox 50.1.0, with whatever Jira version is on atlassian.net right now).

Comment: Ctrl-V actually works everywhere on the page, but seems to work only once... Would the clipboard be reset after the paste?

Comment: Confirmed, I can paste anywhere on the page. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I just found [Shutter](http://shutter-project.org/) that allows one to drag directly from the application window into Jira. It is available on CentOS from the [Nux Repo](http://li.nux.ro/repos.html).

[image]